# Running a docker file from a different location is throwing error

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-modules, docker-for-windows

I am using node application and using Dockerfile to build. I am using the below command to run to generate an image.
I placed all the files under users/node folders

```
docker build -f node/Dockerfile -t my-service .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
From node:alpine    
WORKDIR /usr/node    
COPY ./ ./    
RUN npm install    
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8081');
});
```

**Error Message**

```
 > [4/4] RUN npm install:
#8 2.766 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#8 2.768 npm ERR! syscall open
#8 2.768 npm ERR! path /usr/node/package.json
#8 2.771 npm ERR! errno -2
#8 2.779 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/node/package.json'
#8 2.779 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#8 2.780 npm ERR! enoent
#8 2.787
#8 2.788 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 2.788 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-21T13_36_42_578Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 254
```

When I tried to run after navigating to the node folder the below command was working fine, Not sure why this is failing and running from a different location.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t vineelpellella:visits-service .
```

Any valid inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you `COPY ./ ./`, it copies everything from the directory argument to `docker build`.  If you're running `docker build .` from the parent directory of the directory that contains your application, that would cause this.

Comment: Is there anyway to run this from parent directory

Comment: @VineelPellella try: `docker build -f node/Dockerfile -t my-service ./node`

Comment: In @quentino's command, the `Dockerfile` is in the build-context directory `./node` so you don't need the `-f node/Dockerfile` option.